# Как посмотреть на сайт глазами нового посетителя?

Tags: поддержка, новые-участники

Нашёл в Transifex такую строку:

> Нам всем нравится $site$, но в мире существует огромное количество людей, ищущих ответы на свои вопросы и даже не подозревающих о существовании данного сайта. Каким будет их первое впечатление, когда они перейдут на этот сайт из поисковой выдачи Google? Давайте посмотрим на данный сайт глазами нового посетителя и проверим, как он выглядит на фоне остальных интернет-ресурсов.

Отлично, я хочу посмотреть на Ru.SO глазами нового посетителя. Где это сделать? Раз есть строка, должна быть и страница, которая её использует, ведь так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Эти фразы описывают процесс под названием "самооценки сайта" (site self-evaluation). Можно сравнить с текстом [здесь](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/445).

Такая самооценка проходила каждые полгода на бета-сайтах. Со временем её популярность упала, и летом 2015-го самооценка была [прекращена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601).